# Detecting a control's focus in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, controls, textbox, focus

Is there any way to tell whether a control (specifically a System.Windows.Controls.TextBox) is focused in Silverlight? I'm looking for something like the following (what you would see in a regular .Net application):

```
textBox.Focused
```

This seems like something simple and trivial to leave out from a control, and yet I can't find an answer anywhere.

**Update**

A slightly more elegant solution, incorporating Rob's answer, is to create an extension method like so:

```
public static bool IsFocused( this Control control )
{
    return FocusManager.GetFocusedElement() == control;
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have to use [FocusManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager_members(VS.95).aspx)

```
bool b = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement() == textBox;
```

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why Microsoft decided to handle it this way instead of the way it's handled everywhere else (even their own products)...

Comment: Maybe it helps keep the installer smaller?

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you have a control consisting of more than one input element (which needs to have focus for handling user input) asking the FocusManager won't do the trick anymore.
Try this:

```
private bool HasFocus { get; set; }

protected override void OnGotFocus( RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    base.OnGotFocus( e );
    HasFocus = true;
}

protected override void OnLostFocus( RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    base.OnLostFocus( e );
    HasFocus = false;
}
```