# Get current textBox to make a copy/paste

Tags: c#, silverlight, textbox

I'm making a copy/paste function, but I miss the way to get active textBox.

I have six textBox, and I made this for the moment :

```
    var pressePapier = (ScriptObject)HtmlPage.Window.GetProperty("clipboardData");
    if (pressePapier != null)
    {

        string textSelected = activeTb.SelectedText;

        pressePapier.Invoke("setData", "text", textSelected);
    }
```

How can I get the active textBox, to complete my copy/paste?

Comment: wait, you are doing a copy/paste function on the server-end?

Comment: I made my copy/paste silverlight side. In xaml behind code.

Comment: Why do not use [Clipboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.clipboard(v=vs.95).aspx) class ?

Comment: Yeah ok. But what about get current textBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not familiar with silverlight but think this question should give you the needed answers: [Detecting a control's focus in Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953665/detecting-a-controls-focus-in-silverlight)